# Clear Output Cache from User Control in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

i have a user control with a name `uc_Menu.ascx`. The `menues` are loaded dynamically `Role` base. So, i inlude it in a user control and cached it like this; 
Note: for testing purpose i have just provide 60 sec cache;

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="none" %>
<td id="Menu">
    <div id="firstpane" runat="server" class="menu_list">
        <p class="menu_head">
            <a href="/forms/Dashboard.aspx">
                <span style="background: url('/App_Themes/Default/Images/icons/ic_grid.png') no-repeat"></span>
                DashBoard
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</td>
```

The code behind looks like this;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BulitMenus();
        Response.Write("<h1>" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "</h1>");
    }
}
```

My master page where i have referenced the above user control;

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/uc_Menu.ascx" TagPrefix="Ken" TagName="Menu" %>
<Ken:Menu runat="server" id="Menus" />
```

Now, when i tested this, it works fine (when page is loaded for the first time, cache worked) 
**However, I want to clear the cache when a user click on `LogOff` button (on a master page)** because the menus are role base and an admin might give more permissions to user. In that case it is necessary to relode the menus again. 
So, How do i clear the cache from a user control; 
**Note:** I have also tried this but it deosn't work;
http://aspalliance.com/668_Remove_ASPNET_Page_Output_Cache_Entries

 AND

```
protected void Lbtn_LogOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/UserControls/uc_Menu.ascx");
    // this code is copied from a url above which i have included i my question
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("Pages", DateTime.Now, null,
       System.DateTime.MaxValue, System.TimeSpan.Zero,
       System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);

    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("~/authorization/Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: It's not good idea to use output cache for role-based controls, especially with VaryByParam="none". In your case, once menu is cached for admin, it will be shown for user in the same way. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290098/asp-net-mvc-caching-vary-by-authentication or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109928/how-to-turn-output-caching-off-for-authenticated-users-in-asp-net-mvc etc